# JQuery Text slideDown / slideUp Overlay on Image Keeps Bouncing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to replicate the text overlay effect that occurs when you mouse over an image - found on the [Guardian web site](http://www.guardian.co.uk).

I have it working except when my mouse goes over the **trail-text** area that area bounces (slideDown slideUp) repeatedly a number of times.

I think it is because the **trail-text** area becomes the focus and causes the mouseout event.

Anyway any suggestions/tips would be really helpful.
Many thanks, 
Ben...

#### mypage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang='en-en' xml:lang='en-en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .pixie {
        width: 870px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .strap {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      div.caption{
        padding-left: 10px;
        /*background-color: #a5a5a5;*/
        background-color: #e03d32;
        color: white;
      }
      .caption h3 {
        color: white;
      }

      .pixie a,
      .pixie div,
      .pixie a:hover {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .pixie div.trail-text {
        color: #333;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url(../images/grey-bg.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;
      }

      .pixie div.trail-text {
        display: none;
        margin-top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 2em;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        height: 4.25em;
        width: 870px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src='javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/main.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='pixie'>
      <div class='caption'>
        <h3>Some Big Heading</h3>
        <p class='strap'>Some strapline of stuff</p>
      </div>
      <div class='trail-text'>
        The <strong>Overlay text</strong> which should appear and then disappear.
      </div>

      <img alt='overlay example image' class='imgmain' src='/images/east-hamstead.jpg' title='' />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("div.trail-text").attr("style", "display: none;");

  if ($(".pixie,div.trail-text")) {
    var pixies = $(".pixie,div.trail-text");
    $(pixies).mouseover(function() {
      $(this).find("div.trail-text").slideDown("fast")
    }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).find("div.trail-text").slideUp("fast")
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events bubble upward, which means they fire every time the mouse enters or leaves any element within your div.

You should use jQuery's [`hover`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout) method, like this:

```
$(".pixie,div.trail-text").hover(
    function() { $(this).find("div.trail-text").slideDown("fast"); },
    function() { $(this).find("div.trail-text").slideUp("fast"); }
);
```

Comment: Mouseover doesn't fire every time the mouse is moved, just every time you move the mouse over a child element of the element you attached the event to.

Comment: If you don't want to use hover - use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover and mouseout

Comment: Yes, but hover is more convenient, and there's no reason not to use it.  (Is there?)

Comment: Great - that is perfect. I had tried using hover before but didn't put both elements into the selector, and so still had a problem.
Your solution works perfectly - many thanks.